# What files are required in my HP Recovery partition on Vista

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, windows-vista

My HP Recovery "D" Drive is showing some file in blue and some in black print - it only has 450MB free.  I have this drive backedup on my stand-alone drive.  Are there any files within this partition on my laptop that I can delete?

Answer (score 2):

The files on this partition are needed for recovery in the event of a serious problem.  They should not be deleted as doing so may prevent system recovery.  I am not aware of any files on this partition that are not needed for recovery.  The files in blue type are compressed with NTFS compression to reduce disk space usage.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that this partition is nearly full is irrelevant.  You should not be using this partition for anything.  Do not touch the contents of this partition unless you really know what you are doing.